# Get the RSS/XML feed for an iTunes U Podcast to use in another podcatcher

Tags: itunes, podcasts, podcatcher

There are numerous ways to get the podcast feed for standard iTunes podcasts like [this](http://picklemonkey.net/flipper/convert.php) or [this](http://www.zerologic.com/Blog/How-to-get-the-original-RSS-feed-for-a-podcast-in-iTunes.html), however, neither of these methods work on the podcast feeds in iTunes U.

I don't want to use iTunes, how can I find the alternative xml podcast feed?  Here's one for example: http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/Feed/fora.tv.1901773207.01901773213

How can I subscribe to this feed outside of iTunes?  I have tried emailing the publisher (Fora.tv) numerous times but they never respond.

Comment: What do you use as an alternative pod-catcher? I'm trying to shake iTunes as a pod-catcher but yet to have found a good catcher.

Comment: I haven't found a good iTunes alternative for a PC based podcatcher, but I have an Android phone and primarily use this so the only podcatcher I use is [BeyondPod](http://www.appbrain.com/app/beyondpod-podcast-manager/mobi.beyondpod). I use Google reader to manage all my podcasts, and on the rare occasion that I listen at the computer I stream them directly from Google Reader.  This is no good for the podcasts that only give you access to the last podcast. Ideally I'd like to find a [cloud based podcatcher](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6860/cloud-based-podcatcher).

Comment: I'm also in a quest to find a cloud podcatcher. I'm considering to write my own.

Comment: @mcradle: If you do, let me know, or post a link here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6860/cloud-based-podcatcher

Answer (score 4):

Here is a service that is doing exactly what you want:

- http://itunes.so-nik.com

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Does not work for iTunes-U, which was the question! Fails with: iTunes-U links not supported. 
Currently Apple does not offer a way to subscribe to iTunes-U material outside of iTunes (that i can find). A temporary solution is to search for a similar title as a podcast in hopes that the content providers also posted it to the iTunes Podcast Directory (do no expect this for password protected content).

Comment: Dead link.........

Answer (score 2):

You can get rss feeds using this php tool site

http://itunes.duckdns.org

this site is A web browser based solution

> > EX: https://itunes.apple.com/podcast/state-trance-official-podcast/id260190086?
> >
> > load this link with the ID https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=260190086&entity=podcast
> >
> > Get the "feedUrl" from this json file

solution site makes this process easy. I am using the podcast well with the rss address I get.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this is a site, nevertheless I suggest you read [how do I recommend software in my answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) and read the parts of the answer in **bold**- without a more explanation this might be (mis)attributed as promotional.

Answer (score 1):

If your other reader supports enclosures then simply add the URL to the reader. The server lies about the content type, but the reader should be able to ignore that.

Comment: The only problem with that is that the iTunes server will only accept file request from the iTunes user agent, so I can see the podcasts, but get errors when I download.

Comment: So then tell your reader or player to fake their user agent.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to begin to know how to do that.